# javascript random 8digits in specific number

Tags: javascript, arrays, random

I'm trying to random 8 digits number 0-7 , but `without the 8 and 9`
this is what I've done, but I can't exclude the `8 and 9`

```
var b = Math.floor(Math.random()*90000000) + 10000000;

console.log(b)
```

is there any quick for random the exact 8 digits exclude number? or do I really have to random one by one and `+=` until 8 digits ?

Comment: Yes, our last statement is your solution.  Why do you not want to do that?

Comment: @Amy nah maybe I thought there's quick one , seems none

Comment: You could generate a much larger number, convert to string, replace "8" and "9" and then truncate to 8 digits.  But I suspect generating each digit in a loop would be easier.

Answer (score 4):

Convert to octal (which contains only the digits 0-7) and trim to the desired length:

```
b.toString(8).substr(0, 8)
```

Answer (score 2):

You could get first the max number of the octal system with 8 places and use the decimal system for generating the random value and convert it back to the wanted system.

```js
var max = parseInt(100000000, 8);

console.log(('0000000' + Math.floor(Math.random() * max).toString(8)).slice(-8));
```

Comment: The first time I tried your code, it returned a 7 digit number.

Comment: @ScottMarcus It could even return one digit if `Math.random` return `0`.

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir Well, that was really my point. The OP stated that the result needs to be 8 digits.

Answer (score 0):

You need a number of 8 digits in base 8.
This means you're looking for a (decimal) number between 8^7 and 8^8-1, converted to base 8.
This should do the trick :

```js
// initialize min and max values
var vmin = Math.pow(8,7);
var vmax = Math.pow(8,8)-1;
// compute random number within range
var dec = Math.floor(Math.random()*(vmax-vmin))+vmin;
// convert to base 8
console.log(dec.toString(8));
```

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps you would want something more like this:

```
var b = Math.floor(Math.random()*8);

console.log(b);
```